# How to get the parent node element of a current node variable?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, parent

The below is my xslt:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:call-template name="generateLinks">
        <xsl:with-param name="currentPageBranchVariable" select="//Item[@CurrentPageBranch='true']"></xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>

  </xsl:template>
```

And:

```
  <xsl:template name="generateLinks">
    <xsl:param name="currentPageBranchVariable"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:value-of select="$currentPageBranchVariable/@FullName"/>

    // how to get the parent node of $currentPageBranchVariable?

  </xsl:template>
```

As can be seen, the $currentPageBranchVariable is a variable for the second template which contains an Item node.

How would that be possible to get its parent element from there?

I tried the below but didn't work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../$currentPageBranchVariable/@FullName"/>
<xsl:value-of select="parent::node()/$currentPageBranchVariable/@FullName"/>
<xsl:value-of select="parent($currentPageBranchVariable)/@FullName"/>
```

Hope the question is clear.

Maybe what I'm trying to do is not possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the `$currentPageBranchVariable` is a variable for the second template
>   which contains an `Item` node.
>
> How would that be possible to get its parent element from there?

**Just use**:

```
$currentPageBranchVariable/..
```

this selects the set of parents (one each) of all nodes (in this case just one) contained in `$currentPageBranchVariable` .

Answer (score 2):

You were putting the axis in the wrong spot.

Your expressions were selecting the parent of the context node, not the `$currentPageBranchVariable`.  Since you called the template from a match on `/`, there is no parent to select `@FullName` from.

You need to select the parent from the `$currentPageBranchVariable` by using the parent axis following that variable, not before.

Either of these will work.

```
    <xsl:value-of select="$currentPageBranchVariable/../@FullName" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$currentPageBranchVariable/parent::*/@FullName" />
```